# Upload Speed atrocious on google vm

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, upload, cloud, virtual-machine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYaWF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93iJ.png)

My question is'Why is my application downloading data so slowly from the server?'

Im running a .Net core web application on IIS using a google cloud VM.

The VM machine type is n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory) with a 100gb Standard persistent disk.

Initial load (without any cached) of any view within the application takes a significant amount of time ( see https://theseabay.com/brokerui/js/brokerui.min.js ). Simple images are taking a long time to load as well - See the attached screen shot for examples of file sizes and their loading times.

I did do a network bandwidth check on the server and the upload speed is 0.4mb/s - This seems incredibly slow, given that the download speed is 1200mb/s so not sure if this could be related?

I have also attached a screen shot of the network settings from the google console.

Comment: The first rule in debugging this type of issue: Ask yourself, does this problem affect others? If your problem was true, Google would not have any customers. Therefore, debug your problem as your problem and not Google's. 1) Test the performance from a different location and a different Internet provider. 2) Test the performance going to another public web server on Google. Same problem, it is your Internet / router / wireless access point, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your script 
It's not machine readeable

One of many  Errors 
Misplaced non-space characters inside a table.  
No space between attributes.

JohnC